# orm['model'].objects.create(attr=some_value) causes IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, data-migration

There's a one-to-one forward relationship between my model Backlog and Entity. Each backlog has an entity. 
My code tries to create an entity if a backlog is missing one (it doesn't exist in the db), and links it to the backlog missing the entity.

```
            new_entity = orm['entities.entity'].objects.create(long_name=entity_name)
            if entity_short_name is not None and entity_short_name != '':
                new_entity.name = entity_short_name
            if entity_url is not None:
                new_entity.primary_url = entity_url
            new_entity.save()
            backlog.entity = new_entity
            backlog.save()
```

Each entity object has a unique ID called guid. 
This is the error I get on the code above:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entities_entity_guid_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (guid)=(2f49223d-8732-4582-b8a1-7015f515134a) already exists.
```

Entity model only has one unique key:

```
guid = models.CharField('A globally unique identifier', default = lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), unique = True, db_index = True)
```

What could be causing this Integrity Error? Checking if an entity with this guid exists in the db returns None

**orm is the standard django orm to get objects from the db

```
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 114, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 84, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/usr/local/PATH/0123__.py", line 69, in forwards
    new_entity = orm['entities.entity'].objects.create(long_name=entity_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 157, in create
    return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 322, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entities_entity_guid_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (guid)=(2f49223d-8732-4582-b8a1-7015f515134a) already exists.
```

Comment: Please show the full code and traceback, including the definition of your models and whatever `orm` is.

Comment: Please show your Entity model, specially the part of model where field `guid` is declared.

Comment: @AamirAdnan I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `guid` field is that you are setting the result of a callable `uuid.uuid4()` as default value instead of just setting the callable which will be called every time a new object is created, to fix:

```
def get_unique_id():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

guid = models.CharField('A globally unique identifier', default=get_unique_id, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

Don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after this change.

Comment: I'm sorry but why is declaring the function in line with default (default = lambda(x)) different from your solution?

Comment: Sorry i missed the `lambda` part, but you can't use the `lambda` for `default` the `makemigrations` command will fail as Django can't searlize it. Have you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: Perhaps at one point in time you just set the `default=str(uuid.uuid4())` without lambda, but when you later added the lambda you didn't run makemigrations otherwise it will fail.. ??

Comment: If the default is failing due to the lambda, how am I getting a guid value which is raising the IntegrityError? The problematic guid is being created by orm[...].objects.create() because on checking if this guid previously exists in the db, it doesn't.

Comment: I am not saying lambda is failing, i am saying `makemigrations` will fail because of it when you will run it. Please add full traceback in your question.

Comment: I added the stacktrace.

Comment: It keeps on returning the same guid `2f49223d-8732-4582-b8a1-7015f515134a`. Try to update the guid field as i have done in my code run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` and check if error goes away.